# Vuetify font is different in production vs dev

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've noticed that my deployed app is using a different font to the dev app. I've tried multiple methods of setting the font in the deployed app but I'm having it default to `Roboto`.
There are various solutions that I've tried but none seem to overwrite the default font CSS.

Here is my `SCSS` in the `App.vue` component.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light'),
  url('./fonts/ITCAvantGardeStdXLt.woff') format('woff');
}

$heading-font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';
$font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';
$body-font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';
$title-font: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';

.v-application {
  [class*='text-'] {
    font-family: $font-family, 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light' !important;
  }

  font-family: $font-family, 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light' !important;
}
```

**Dev CSS in Chrome**

[image: dev css]

[image: dev css]

**Production CSS in Chrome**

[image: production header]

[image]

What is the correct method of setting the default font for all elements?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are directly changing the `.v-application` class which is a bad way of doing it. Please use official way to change it using SASS variables. Here's the [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#example-variable-file).

> $body-font-family: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std Extra Light';

I know you are using `$body-font-family` but I am pretty sure that the variables are not working as you have added them in your `App.vue` SCSS. Remove `.v-application` classes and follow the [guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install) properly to get it working.

> Create a folder called sass, scss or styles in your src directory with a file named variables.scss or variables.sass. The vuetify-loader will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI’s compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults.

Comment: The documentation mentioned `Vue CLI`, `Nuxt Install` and `Webpack Install`. I might be wrong but I don't believe I'm using any of these.
My app is using Meteor with VueJS and I can't see any webpack configurations or similar. What would be the right way of adding the SCSS file?

Comment: How did you initialized your project?

Comment: Sorry I added my comment before finishing writing. I created it using Meteors create VueJS command.

Comment: Here is an example project I created to show you the structure of the project. 
https://github.com/Michael2109/meteor-vue-typescript-example

Comment: You can use [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-use-webpack/55376/2).

Comment: The problem I have is how do I import in the SCSS/SASS file? 
I've tried adding the `variables.scss` to the `imports` directory and tried importing it into the `client/main.ts` but it says it can't find the module.

Comment: I don't see how I can add the file with what you mentioned. I can create a file like specified in the link you sent but how do I go about importing it? 
I can't find any examples online.